# User authentication + Twitter/Facebook feeds (jQuery Mobile/PhoneGap)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, feed

I would like to ask you, would it be possible to implement Twitter or Facebook user authentication feature using jQuery (Mobile/PhoneGap) and accordingly show their live news feeds on the mobile iOS (PhoneGap based) application?
Like the current Facebook app but much simpler: log in (authentication window appears) -> user news feed - nothing more.

I found something similar https://github.com/rsepulveda2/Twitter-Mobile but apparently this was updated 2 years ago and does not seem fully funcional.

If yes, please let me know any useful guides or tutorials.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's actually possible for Facebook, using a plugin provided by PhoneGap:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

In the readme file you can find a tutorial. Once you have followed all the steps in that tutorial you can use normally the Facebook API with javascript using the documentation provided:

https://developers.facebook.com/web/

For the moment it's only implemented for android and iOS, but they'd probably update it for the other platforms.

For twitter you can use these other PhoneGap Plugins:
github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins